# How to create a numpy array with a an extra dimension depending on an where clause?

Tags: python, numpy

## Problem

I need to create an array that takes the argmax and based on that maximum value position fill the array with `[1,0]` while the other fields that are not the maximum will be filled with `[0,1]`.

### Example:

Given the vector `a`:

```
a.shape = (3,2)
a = np.array([[1,0],[1,2],[1,3]])
```

Return the vector `b`:

```
b.shape = (3,2,2)
b = np.array([[[1,0],[0,1]],[[0,1],[1,0]],[[0,1],[1,0]]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
b = np.empty(tuple(list(a.shape) + [2]))
b[range(len(c)), c, :] = [1, 0]
b[range(len(c)), ~c, :] = [0, 1]
b
>>>array([[[1., 0.],
           [0., 1.]],

          [[0., 1.],
           [1., 0.]],

          [[0., 1.],
           [1., 0.]]])
```

Note this only works in this example since the argmax will ever be only 0 or 1. If the second dimension in `a` is greater than 2 I don't think that this solution will work

Comment: Thanks. I also made a similar solution, not sure which one is more computationally efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a function that returns the desirable result but will only work for two classes. It could be adapted for multiple classes:

```
a = np.array([[1,0],[1,2],[1,3]])

def create_dist_prob_target(arr):
    p_ = np.squeeze(arr,axis=1)
    a = np.expand_dims(np.where((p_ == np.amax(p_,axis = 1)[:,None]),1,0),axis=-1)
    b = np.expand_dims(np.where((p_ == np.amax(p_,axis = 1)[:,None]),0,1),axis=-1)
    return np.concatenate((a,b),axis=2)

b = create_dist_prob_target(a)
print(b)
```